# How to read filenames from input files and copy them to different locations

Tags: shell-script

I have 2 different input files

File  A:

```
1.dat
2.dat
3.dat
```

File B:

```
4.dat
5.dat
5.dat
```

Now, I want to find each dat file from file A from `$LOCATION/` then want to copy to `$FILE_A_PATH`
then want to find each dat file from file B from `$LOCATION/` then want to copy to `$FILE_B_PATH`

Please help to achieve this

Comment: The process for file B is identical to the process for file A. Have you tried some command to copy the files? Where do you face difficulties?

Comment: while IFS= read -r fileA || IFS= read r file B
do 
find $LOCATION -type f "$fileA" -exec cp -n {} $FILE_A_PATH \;
if [ -f $FILE_A_PATH/$fileA ];
then
echo $fileA copied successfully
else
echo $fileA does not exist
fi

find $LOCATION -type f "$fileB" -exec cp -n {} $FILE_B_PATH \;
if [ -f $FILE_A_PATH/$fileB ];
then
echo $fileB copied successfully
else
echo $fileB does not exist
fi
done <fileA 3<fileB

Getting the o/p like below which is not the desired one:
1.dat copied successfully
does not exist
does not exist
does not exist
2.dat copied sucssfully

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `xargs` and `cp`, that could be:

```
(
  cd -P -- "$LOCATION" &&
    xargs -rd '\n' cp -t "$FILE_A_LOCATION" --
) < 'File A'
```

And same for `File B`.

If the `dat` files are to be looked for potentially in subdirectories of `$LOCATION` and you want to copy one of them, say the most recent to `$FILE_A_LOCATION`, with the `zsh` shell:

```
autoload zargs
cp_from_file() (
  file=$1 dest=$2
  files=( ${(f)"$(<$file)"} )
  newests=( $LOCATION/**/$^files(ND.om[1]) )
  zargs -r -- $newests -- cp -t $dest --
)
cp_from_file 'File A' $FILE_A_LOCATION
cp_from_file 'File B' $FILE_B_LOCATION
```